# What is the purpose of Big-O notation in computer science if it doesn't give all the information needed?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

What is the use of Big-O notation in computer science if it doesn't give all the information needed?

For example, if one algorithm runs at `1000n` and one at `n`, it is true that they are both `O(n)`. But I still may make a foolish choice based on this information, since one algorithm takes 1000 times as long as the other for any given input.

I *still* need to know *all* the parts of the equation, including the constant, to make an informed choice, so what is the importance of this "intermediate" comparison? I end up loosing important information when it gets reduced to this form, and what do I gain?

Comment: _all_ the details means the actual algorithm.  There isn't any good way to make it shorter than that.

Comment: No, not the algorithm. Just the equation representing its repeated/time consuming operations. I don't need the actual code for that.

Comment: It's really about how different algorithms *scale*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does that constant factor represent? You can't say with certainty, for example, that an algorithm that is O(1000n) will be slower than an algorithm that's O(5n). It might be that the 1000n algorithm loads all data into memory and makes 1,000 passes over that data, and the 5n algorithm makes five passes over a file that's stored on a slow I/O device. The 1000n algorithm will run faster even though its "constant" is much larger.

In addition, some computers perform some operations more quickly than other computers do. It's quite common, given two O(n) algorithms (call them A and B), for A to execute faster on one computer and B to execute faster on the other computer. Or two different implementations of the same algorithm can have widely varying runtimes on the same computer.

Asymptotic analysis, as others have said, gives you an indication of how an algorithm's running time varies with the size of the input. It's useful for giving you a good starting place in algorithm selection. Quick reference will tell you that a particular algorithm is O(n) or O(n log n) or whatever, but it's very easy to find more detailed information on most common algorithms. Still, that more detailed analysis will only give you a constant number without saying how that number relates to real running time.

In the end, the only way you can determine which algorithm is right for you is to study it yourself and then test it against your expected data.

In short, I think you're expecting too much from asymptotic analysis. It's a useful "first line" filter. But when you get beyond that you have to look for more information.

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly noted, it does not give you information on the exact running time of an algorithm. It is mainly used to indicate the *complexity* of an algorithm, to indicate if it is linear in the input size, quadratic, exponential, etc. This is important when choosing between algorithms if you know that your input size is large, since even a `1000n` algorithm well beat a `1.23 exp(n)` algorithm for large enough `n`.

In real world algorithms, the hidden 'scaling factor' is of course important. It is therefore not uncommon to use an algorithm with a 'worse' complexity if it has a lower scaling factor. Many practical implementations of sorting algorithms are [for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) 'hybrid' and will resort to some 'bad' algorithm like [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) (which is `O(n^2)` but very simple to implement) for `n < 10`, while changing to [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (which is `O(n log(n))` but more complex) for `n >= 10`.

Answer (score 2):

It's main purpose is for rough comparisons of logic.  The difference of `O(n)` and `O(1000n)` is large for `n ~ 1000` (n roughly equal to 1000) and `n < 1000`, but when you compare it to values where `n >> 1000` (n much larger than 1000) the difference is miniscule.

You are right in saying they both scale linearly and knowing the coefficient helps in a detailed analysis but generally in computing the difference between linear (`O(cn)`) and exponential (`O(cn^x)`) performance is more important to note than the difference between two linear times. There is a larger value in the comparisons of runtime of higher orders such as  and  Where the performance difference scales exponentially.

The overall purpose of Big O notation is to give a sense of relative performance time in order to compare and further optimize algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Big-O tells you how the runtime or memory consumption of a process changes as the size of its input changes. O(n) and O(1000n) are both still O(n) -- if you double the size of the input, then for all practical purposes the runtime doubles too.

Now, we can have an O(n) algorithm and an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm where the coefficient of n is 1000000 and the coefficient of n<sup>2</sup> is 1, in which case the O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm would outperform the O(n) for smaller n values. This doesn't change the fact, however, that the second algorithm's runtime grows more rapidly than the first's, and this is the information that big-O tells us. There will be some input size at which the O(n) algorithm begins to outperform the O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the hidden impact of the constant term, complexity notation also only considers the worst case instance of a problem.

Case in point, the simplex method (linear programming) has exponential complexity for all known implementations.  However, the simplex method works much faster in practice than the provably polynomial-time interior point methods.

Complexity notation has much value for theoretical problem classification.  If you want some more information on practical consequences check out "Smoothed Analysis" by Spielman:  http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman

This is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it doesn't give you *all* information, but there's no single metric in any field that does that.

Big-O notation tells you how *quickly* the performance gets worse, as your dataset gets larger. In other words, it describes the type of performance *curve*, but not the absolute performance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Big-O notation is useful to express an algorithm's scaling performance as it falls into one of three basic categories:

- Linear
- Logarithmic (or "linearithmic")
- Exponential

It is possible to do deep analysis of an algorithm for very accurate performance measurements, but it is time consuming and not really necessary to get a broad indication of performance.